# changing default search result

Tags: 2007, search, forms-services

We have a form library that contains our servers information. When someone is looking for some server form through the search feature, the metadata in the result set always references the person who created the form, not its last modifier.

Is there any way to change the search result as to display the last modifier's name instead of the creator's name?

Comment: As of today, I haven't been able to find an answer to this question anywhere on the internet.